# How to write unit test with okhttp using Mockito & Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, mockito, okhttp

I am trying to use okhttp with Mockito in my spring boot application but I am always getting NullPointerException at line

httpClient.newCall(request).execute()

How do we use Mockito with okhttp?

```
@Component
public class HStatus {

    @Autowired
    private OkHttpClient httpClient;

    public int HCheck() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        String url = new URIBuilder("Some URL").build().toString();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build();

        try (Response resp = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {

            return resp.code();

        }

    }
```

In junit, I am trying to do -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HStatusTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private HStatus hStatus;

    @Mock
    private OkHttpClient httpClient;


    @Test
    public void TestHCheck_Should_Return_200_StatusCode() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        Response resp = new Response.Builder()
                .request(new Request.Builder().url("SOME URL").build())
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(200).message("")
                .build();

        Mockito.when(httpClient.newCall(ArgumentMatchers.any()).execute).thenReturn(resp);

// Getting NullPointer at this call -> httpClient.newCall(ArgumentMatchers.any()).execute

        int statusCode = hStatus.HCheck();
        
        assertEquals(200, statusCode);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please update with more context, including the surrounding code and the test code.

Comment: Also, okhttp source code is available. It has its own tests. Why repeat them? Perhaps you should instead use rest-assured or wiremock to test an actual server?

Comment: You should return a mocked response via a server, not from a client execution https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are creating new instance of OkHttpClient.

For new instance creating not easy to mock them with mockito. You can use mockito @Spy but i don't prefer that.

Otherwise you can use powermock

```
 OkHttpClient mockClient = mock(OkHttpClient.class);
 PowerMockito.whenNew(OkHttpClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockClient);
```

Another way:
create a getter class for new OkHttpClient(); and mock it.

```
getClient(){
    return new OkHttpClient();
}
```

In mockito

```
when(class.getClient()).thenReturn(mockClient);
```

Comment: A client shouldn't be mocked. The server and response should be